# Can an Akka Actor Handle Multiple Message Types in Akka Typed

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

Is it possible to handle multiple message types from a single actor.

For example, assume there is an actor called `TradingStrategy` that trades stocks. It takes in pricing data pumped in from another Actor. When it decides to place a trade, it sends a message to an another Actor, call it `OrderActor`, to place a trade. But the `TradingStrategy` Actor is interested in knowing whether or not the order placed was successful or rejected, etc... because it may change its strategy based on the results from the place order action. In this example, it seems the `TradingStrategy` needs to handle messages for **pricing updates AND order updates**. Is this possible with Akka typed? Are there ways to handle this situation?

Here is a code example:
`IEXData` is the data message.

```
  def apply(orderActor: ActorRef[OrderCommand]): Behavior[IEXData] = Behaviors.setup { context =>
    new SimpleTradingStrategy(context, brokerActor)
  }
}

class SimpleTradingStrategy(
    context: ActorContext[IEXData],
    orderActor: ActorRef[OrderCommand],
    ticker: Ticker = "spy"
) extends AbstractBehavior[IEXData](context) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TradingStrategy`'s protocol would have to include messages indicating order updates.  A `TradingStrategy` actor can register a message adapter which will translate the messages sent by the order actor into `TradingStrategy`'s protocol: the `TradingStrategy` can present the "virtual" `ActorRef` returned by the message adapter to the order actor without the order actor knowing that its a `TradingStrategy`.

Comment: Thank you @levi-ramsey. Related, to this question is one regarding proper handling of Futures inside of Actors. Assume the OrderActor relies on some web service to fill orders, is it "OK" to ```map``` on futures from within the OrderActor ... like so:

orderFacade
          .getOrder(orderId)
          .map(res => {
             //translate and then replyTo ! result
         
            )
          })

Comment: It's safer in Akka Typed (especially if using the functional API) than it would be in Classic: there's less mutable actor state that could result in chaos (the explicit `replyTo` solves the single biggest foot-gun in that area), but it's still not something I'd recommend doing.  `context.pipeToSelf` is guaranteed to be OK and has minimal overhead compared to `map`.